# Upgrade CPLEX to Academic License Mac

Tags: macos, installation, cplex

I have created a linear programming model in Python and want to solve this with the CPLEX solver on MacOS High Sierra. If I keep the problem small, the solver works just fine, if I increase the size of the problem I get the following message:

`CPLEX Error 1016: Promotional version`

I've downloaded the Student version to surpass this limitation of the free version of CPLEX Studio and got the .bin file:

`cplex_studio129.linux-x86-64.bin`

If I try to install it in my terminal, I get the following message:

```
Preparing to install
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

JRE libraries are missing or not compatible....
Exiting....
```

I've tried to use LAX_VM /Library/Java, reinstalled Java as well, but without succes. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally got it working, thanks for the input @xavier-nodet! Here is my solution for others with the same problem:

I installed the academic version of CPLEX with the following command as described in the instructions:
`python setup.py install --home /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

However, the files are placed in the following dir:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lib/python/`

I manually moved the cplex and docplex folders to the site-packages directory, thats it!

Comment: As is, this should not be the accepted answer. The Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-unix-the-prefix-scheme) explains how to use the various alternate installation arguments (e.g., `--home`, `--prefix`, etc.). It looks like you should be using `python setup.py install --prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6` and this would avoid this extra business of copying files around.

Comment: In addition, it looks like part of your problem is that you have different versions of Python installed (e.g., anaconda mentioned in comments above vs the standard system Python mentioned here) and this is probably the source of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

You downloaded a Linux version (`linux-x86-64`) of CPLEX, instead of the version for macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My bad! I also have the MacOS version installed with the .dmg file. But in Python (I use Jupyter Notebook) I still get the error message 1016 if I try to solve a bigger problem. Somehow the standard docplex that is installed with the help of pip is still imported instead of the installed academic version. I've followed several tutorials now trying to overwrite these installations but without succes. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Did you run the `setup.py` that comes in the installation of CPLEX Optimization Studio, using the same Python environment that you use for your Jupiter notebooks?

Comment: Yes I did! The error message I does refer to the docplex package. Could this be a indication for the source of the problem?

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docplex/mp/error_handler.py in fatal_limits_exceeded(self)
    212     def fatal_limits_exceeded(self):
    213         docplex_error_stop_here()
--> 214         raise DOcplexLimitsExceeded()
    215 
    216 `

I also tried to solve the problem by setting the PYTHONPATH variable, but without succes.

Comment: In addition. Is it correct that this should be the directory to install the package? `/Users/Martijn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cplex`